# Multi Select look up

Tags: lookup

multiselect in lookup I get error Static Resource named lookupwindow does not exist. Check spelling  here:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.lookupwindowHeader, 'image/lookupwindowhr.gif')}" />
```

what should this be?

Answer (score 1):

It's whatever you uploaded it as; check Setup > Develop > Static Resources. If you're following some sort of tutorial, there's a file you need to need to download, then upload into the Static Resources area.

Answer (score -1):

ok no tutorial it was a post in salesforce exchange. I added what I needed and that is the error I got. It does not show up in static source. would that be the apex I made that it needs to look for?